# How to remove all references in a XSD schema

Tags: xsd, schema

For example, I have a schema like this:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:pref="http://someaddr.com" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://otheraddr.com">
   <xs:element name="rootElem">
     <xs:complexType>
       <xs:sequence>
         <xs:element ref="pref:elem1" minoccurs="1" and maxoccurs="2"/>
         <xs:element ref="pref:elem2" minoccurs="1" and maxoccurs="2"/>
       </xs:sequence>
     </xs:complexType>
   </xs:element>
   <xs:element name="elem1" type="xs:string"/>
   <xs:element name="elem2" type="xs:date"/>
</xs:schema>
```

and I would like to transform to and keep all the global element declaration and the min. max occurence details as well

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:pref="http://someaddr.com" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://otheraddr.com">
           <xs:element name="rootElem">
             <xs:complexType>
               <xs:sequence>
                 <xs:element name="elem1" type="xs:string" minoccurs="1" and maxoccurs="2"/>
                 <xs:element name="elem2" type="xs:string" minoccurs="1" and maxoccurs="2" />
               </xs:sequence>
             </xs:complexType>
           </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="elem1" type="xs:string"/>
           <xs:element name="elem2" type="xs:date"/>
        </xs:schema
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I think you've got a few choices

- The simplest might be to open your xsd in something like Notepad++ and do a simple find and replace - e.g. you could replace.
- As an alternative you could create a simple version of your xml document and run it though XSD (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s(v=vs.110).aspx) to create a new xsd and then modify it to match your needs.

In both cases I suggest running it through a validator - the W3C one is pretty good https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s(v=vs.110).aspx.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i am looking to use an XSLT script to modify so that it can be used as part of an process flow